# Trace a module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, trace

I have a python file some_file.py in directory A which I call as a module like: `python3 -m A.some_file`

I want to [trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) execution of this python call and see each line being printed while it executes. How can I do it?

Comment: Use a debugger: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: The very link you gave has an example of tracing a module. What exactly is your question? What specific problem have you encountered doing what you link should be done?

Comment: MisterMiyagi the ability to trace a module was added after this question was asked, so it makes sense in context. As you explained to me in your comment, the feature was introduced in Python 3.8. Python 3.8 was released on October 14th, 2019. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the Python `trace` module does not support running another module. I suggest creating a temporary script for the trace.

Assuming your file structure is:

```
./
  A/
    some_file.py
```

First, refactor `some_file.py` so that all of its "main" function code is in a function called `main()`. Then call `main()` from within the main section of the module. If you are following the common `if __name__ == '__main__'` convention, this is as simple as changing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # my main code here
```

to:

```
def main():
    # my main code here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then, create a temporary script mytrace.py in the current directory ./ with the following contents:

```
import A

A.some_file.main()
```

Your new file structure should be:

```
./
  mytrace.py
  A/
    some_file.py
```

Now, you should be able to run:

```
python3 -m trace --trace mytrace.py
```

Comment: ["*New in version 3.8*: Added ``--module`` option that allows to run an executable module."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html#command-line-usage)